# why use "continue;" statement when I can modify if (condition)

Tags: java, algorithm, continue

I did some research on importance and existence of continue; statement in Java. 
I can't understand why it exists, when we can modify our if(condition) to do exactly what we want to achieve.

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("with continue: odd number " + i++);
    }
    System.out.println("--------");
    i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        System.out.println("without continue: odd number " + i++);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` is more useful when the content of your loop is much more complicated than your example. That said, you can always manage without it.

For example, this code :

```
while (something) 
{
   if (cond1)
      continue;
   if (cond2)
      continue;
   ....
   if (cond3)
      continue;
   ....
}
```

Can be replaced with this code :

```
while (something)
{
    if (!cond1) {
        if (!cond2) {
           ....
           if (!cond3) {
               ....
           }
       }            
    }
}
```

Using `continue` can make the code more readable in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Also `continue` can be use with `label statement` .

> A label provides a statement with an identifier that lets you refer to
>   it elsewhere in your program.

```
class A
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[][] = new int[][]{{1,2},{2,3}, {3,4}, {4,5}};

        Outer:
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < arr[i].length ; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
                    continue Outer;
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *always* find a case where your proposed improvement won't work so well, usually something a lot more complex, or involving more than *one* `continue` statement. And, yes, you can generally also refactor it so that it's much easier to do.

But sometimes, `continue` is the easiest solution to the problem.

In any case, the reason it exists is almost certainly because, like C++, Java built on C, at least for the basic flow control stuff.